# How to retrieve data from parent-child tables using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, join

In my Spring Boot app, I use Hibernate and applied the necessary relations to the following entities properly.

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=50)
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class RecipeIngredient {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RecipeIngredientId recipeIngredientId = new RecipeIngredientId();

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("recipeId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Recipe recipe;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("ingredientId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredients = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Now I am trying to retrieve data by merging related entities. For example, when retrieving a Recipe, I also need to retrieve all Ingredients belonging to this Recipe.

As far as I know, I can use Projection and maybe it is better to only use Hibernate features and retrieve related table data via `Java Stream`. I have no idea how should I retrieve data via Hibernate.

Suppose that I just need an `Optional<Recipe>` that has `List<Ingredient>`. Then, I probably need a DTO class something like that:

```
@Data
public class ResponseDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String title;

    List<RecipeIngredient> ingredients;

    // getter, setter, constructor
}
```

So, how should I populate this DTO with the requested Recipe and corresponding Ingredient data (getting Ingredient names besides id values) using `Java Stream`?

Or if you suggest Projection way, I tried it but the data is multiplied by the ingredient count belonging to the searched recipe.

**Update:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String title;

    List<IngredientDTO> ingredientDTOList;

    public ResponseDTO(Recipe recipe) {
        this.id = recipe.getId();
        this.title = recipe.getTitle();

        this.ingredientDTOList = recipe.getRecipeIngredients().stream()
                .map(ri -> new IngredientDTO(ri.getIngredient().getName()))
                .toList();
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class IngredientDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public IngredientDTO(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your model use a class for the relationship between `Recipe` and `Ingredient`? It seems that `Recipe` should have a collection of `Ingredient` directly; JPA/Hibernate will take care of managing the relationship table if you want it stored that way.

Comment: @E-Riz Thanks for help. Actually my problem is mapping collection to DTO class using Java Stream. Could you please post an example usage for this scenario?

Comment: By the way, when I use this DTO, it returns the related table data, but too many recursion. Is there something that I need to add for preventing unnecessary recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in the `ResponseDTO` you will need you change the type of ingredients from `List<RecipeIngredient>` to `List<Ingredient>`.

To manually perform the mapping, you should use (to map from a suppose Recipe recipe to a `RespondeDTO` response):

```
ResponseDTO recipeToResponseDTO(Recipe recipe) {
    ResponseDTO response = new ResponseDTO();
    response.setId(recipe.getId());
    response.setTitle(recipe.getTitle());
    response.setIngredients(recipe.recipeIngredients.stream()
            .map(RecipeIngredient::getIngredient()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return response;
}
```

On the other hand, to model a n-n relation, I encourage you to use the approach proposed by E-Riz in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for reply Ivan. Do you mean that in Ingredient entity changing from Set<T> to List<T>?

Comment: Yeah, I decided to use Hibernate way and directly mapping the result to DTO. Now I have a infinitive recursion problem and actually I can solve it using some json annotations. **BUT** I want to fix it using proper equals and hashcode methods in my Entities by excluding Collections fields.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new so I forgot to write the escape characters. I corrected my answer, I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Actually the result seems properly on the IntelliJ debugger, but ingredients are null on Postman. Any idea?

Comment: If I solved this problem, probably I will get the ingredients: ""status": 500,
    "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class ResponseDTO]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class ResponseDTO and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: ApiResponse[\"data\"]->.... \"]->java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN[0])"

Comment: Any idea about the solution? Probably due to infinitive lazy loading, but I tried many things :(

Comment: can you add your ResponseDTO class full code? and make sure that the getters for that class are public

Comment: And also, make the List<Ingredients> into private List<Ingredients> to prevent the list from being package protected and if the answer was useful marked it so it can help other people :)

Comment: **You rock!..** While adding details to my question, I realized that I made a big mistake :( I forgot to add Setter/Getter to my IngredientDTO that is used for list and that's why the values are not set even if they were coming to my Controller. Thanks you so much for your wonderful helps.

Comment: By the way, I think it is good to create a new DTO for Ingredient list instead of using Ingredient entity. What would you suggest?

Comment: And I cannot vote up you as I don't have enough repo. Would you consider voting up for the question?

Comment: I voted up as I have enough repo. Any idea for my last comments?